# Unknown error in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to learn how to use React and I'm trying to build a todo app. Right now my index.js file is as such:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDom = require('react-dom');

//create component
var TodoComponent = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return(
            <h1>Hello!</h1>
        );
    }
});

//put component into html page
ReactDom.render(<TodoComponent/>, document.getElementById('todo-wrapper'))
```

but in my terminal I get this error:

```
ERROR in ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactMount.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'react/lib/React' in /Users/tylerbray/Documents/Side Projects/Ninja React/react-playlist/node_modules/react-dom/lib
 @ ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactMount.js 15:12-38
```

here is my json file:

```
{
  "name": "react-playlist",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A simple react to-do list",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "npm run build",
    "build": "webpack -d && webpack-dev-server --content-base src/ --inline --hot --port 1234"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/iamshaunjp/react-playlist.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "react"
  ],
  "author": "The Net Ninja",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/iamshaunjp/react-playlist/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/iamshaunjp/react-playlist#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.4.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^1.15.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.5"
  }
}
```

I'm not sure what to make of it and I was hoping someone here could point me in the right direction. Repo can be found here: https://github.com/Brayheart/react-todo

Comment: document.getElementById(todo-wrapper) should be document.getElementById('todo-wrapper')

Comment: thankyou for pointing that out, I have updated the post and made the changes to my file

Answer (score 3):

```
var React = require('require');
```

should be:

```
var React = require('react');
```

Comment: I noticed that as soon as i posted it, unfortunately it does not fix the error I have updated the post

Comment: Did you `npm install react`?  Is it in your node_modules?  If you are using `require` you need to give it the path like: `require("./node_modules/react")`  If you are using Babel `import` statements, you can `import React from 'react'`

Comment: I attempted using import statements and giving direct paths to the node module file. Neither were able to fix the error. My repo can be found here https://github.com/Brayheart/react-todo If possible I'd love to use the import statements rather than giving the pathing to the module file

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that you are using "react-dom": "^15.6.2" which is creating an issue. Packaging has changed after react 16, There is no react/lib/* and react-dom/lib/* anymore (check docs for more details: https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/26/react-v16.0.html#packaging).

To fix an issue

1. update "react-dom" to "^16.2.0".
2. Remove node_modules
3. Run "npm install"
4. Then you also need to change your "index.js" as you have upgraded react version. "React.createClass" is not a part of core package anymore it is extracted to separate package "create-react-class" (for more details check docs: https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/26/react-v16.0.html#packaging), So i have modified it to use React.component.

   ```
   import React from 'react';
   import ReactDom from 'react-dom';

   //create component 
   class TodoComponent extends React.Component {
       render() {
           return(
               <h1>Hello!</h1>
           );
       }
   }

   //put component into html page
   ReactDom.render(<TodoComponent/>, document.getElementById('todo-
   wrapper'))
   ```
5. run "npm start"
6. Opened app using url http://localhost:1234

it should work :)

Comment: I like you. Make sure you're on the lesson-4 branch and NOT the master branch. I'm working on someone elses repo and trying to follow them along via youtube, but from what I can find online, I guess react is updated so the guy im following along is building react in an out of date style. I couldn't get  the error to fix so I found another channel that is building an app with Reacts updated code.

Comment: @Brayheart i have edited my answer. Try it now it should fix your issue. Also accept it as answer if it works.. :)